# Mongoose schemas not picking up new properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema, I added updated_by and created_by, but for some reason when I save models from client to server, those fields aren't visible:

```
   userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            role: {
                type: String,
                enum: ['Admin', 'Owner', 'User']
            },
            username: {
                type: String,
                unique: true,
                required: true,
                validate: [validation.usernameValidator, 'not a valid username']
            },
            passwordHash: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                validate: [validation.passwordValidator, 'not a valid password']
            },
            email: {
                type: String,
                unique: true,
                required: true,
                validate: [validation.emailValidator, 'not a valid email address']
            },
            firstName: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            lastName: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            registered_at: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            created_by: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            updated_by: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            created_at: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            updated_at: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        },
        {
            autoIndex: false
        });
```

is this normally a problem? Do I have to somehow rebuild something with Mongoose or MongoDB in order for them to pick up the new properties on this model?

Of course, I did restart the mongoDB server, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, if you save your User model, the fields with actual values shown in MongoDB will be the ones you set a value for yourself when saving the model OR the fields with a default value set in your userSchema.

So, just to clarify on this:

```
    address: { type: String, default: ' ' }
```

will be shown in MongoDB with a value of  ' '  unless you set a specific address when saving your User model.

But,

```
    address: String
```

will **NOT** be shown in MongoDB unless you set a specific address when saving your User model.

**EDIT**
Thanks to Matthew for pointing it out, actually upsert behavior is indeed the following:

> If upsert is true and no document matches the query criteria, update() inserts a single document.

Comment: Upsert will create a new document if the conditional does not match any documents in the database, which would not solve his problem at all.  However, you are correct in that no field will be saved to the database that doesn't have a value set and doesn't have a default value specified in the Schema, which is the the solution to the problem @AlexMills is having.